# How to suppress failure output from RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Output has 3 sections:

```
Failures:

  1) Spec name
     Failure/Error: return ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query_string) if Rails.env.test?

     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function group_concat(character varying, unknown) does not exist
       LINE 1: SELECT ...
                                   ^
       HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
     # ./app/models/...
     # ./app/models/...
     # ./app/models/...
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # PG::UndefinedFunction:
     #   ERROR:  function group_concat(character varying, unknown) does not exist
     #   LINE 1: SELECT ... as...
     #                               ^
     #   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
     #   ./app/models/....rb:7:in `query'

Finished in 15.8 seconds (files took 12.76 seconds to load)
69 examples, 11 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/foo_spec.rb:385 # ...
rspec ./spec/models/foo_spec.rb:385 # ...
rspec ./spec/models/foo_spec.rb:385 # ...
```

There are many failues, and I am more interested in the total number of failures.

How to limit the output to:

```
Finished in 15.8 seconds (files took 12.76 seconds to load)
69 examples, 11 failures
```

Comment: If none of the stock formatting options meet your needs (those linked to by @dbugger), you can also build your own: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/formatters/custom-formatters

Comment: @dbugger - That link didn't help, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer I was looking for, but this works well:

```
rspec | grep examples
```